# Binding values on controllers

Tags: ember.js, binding

I have two controllers, `SidebarCategoriesController` and `MainLinksController`. I have a property `selectedCategory` on `SidebarCategoriesController` and `MainLinksController` needs this property when rendering templates.

```
App.MainLinksController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
     needs: "sidebarCategories"
});

App.SidebarCategoriesController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    selectedCategory:2,
    actions: {
        setCategory: function (id){
            this.set('selectedCategory',id);
        }
    }
});
```

I also have a templete(below) whose controller is MainLinksController:

```
<script  type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="main_links">
 <h2 class="panel-title">All links:{{controllers.sidebarCategories.selectedCategory}}</h2>
</script>
```

The issue is that when `selectedCategory` is being updated in `SidebarCategoriesController`, the template which is using `selectedCategory` from `MainLinksController` via `{{controllers.sidebarCategories.selectedCategory}}` is not getting updated. How can i make the binding so that as soon as the `selectedCategory`  changes in `SidebarCategoriesController`, `{{controllers.sidebarCategories.selectedCategory}}` also changes in the template ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modified your jsbin to get it to work as follows:

```
App.CategoryManagerController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  selectedCategory: 5
});

App.SidebarCategoriesController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    needs: ['categoryManager'],
    selectedCategory: Ember.computed.alias('controllers.categoryManager.selectedCategory'),
    actions: {
        setCategory: function (){
            this.set('selectedCategory', 3);
        }
    }
});

App.MainLinksController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    needs: ['categoryManager'],
    selectedCategory: Ember.computed.alias('controllers.categoryManager.selectedCategory')
});
```

Full working solution [here](http://jsbin.com/dipudu/1/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: is the route and resource important in this, because i'm using only route and specifying my model in this.render method

Comment: look at this example here: https://gist.github.com/noorbakerally/c5fe53eb645766846631 which is in jsbin here, http://jsbin.com/sihili

There are two controllers, SidebarCategoriesController and MainLinksController. I was expecting selectedCategory to be updated in MainLinksController as soon as selectedCategory gets updated in SidebarCategoriesController but selectedCategory in MainLinksController doesn't get updated

Comment: I modified my answer to include a full working solution. Your solution "looked" right and I am not sure why it doesn't work, but I got it to work, so check it out

Comment: This issue puzzled me loads, Thanks :)